# background image also header image cc trick how to do it?

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is the right way/place to ask, but on this website

http://www.santacruzbicycles.com/en/us

they have a statick background image, that does not move, but when you scroll the page, the text goes over the picture, a very cool effect.

does anyone have a css tutorial or pointers, to how I can make a similar effect?

edit: clarifying what I try to do:

[image: webpage as it first appear]
[image: webpage after scrolling a little]
[image: webpage after scolling some more]

Comment: I can not find this anywhere, hope some one have some hints

Comment: strange that it was put on hold after it was answered. Mr Anju understood quite clearly what I wanted, and helped me out a lot.

Comment: I have added some screen shots, hope this explains better, I just want to make sure my new friend Anju gets his credit for helping me, and maybe other can also learn from this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case, the div that contains the background image is made fixed.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

along with the background image css they put

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

to make that image to attached at the top.

Comment: ok, I can get the background to be fixed, but how can I make the text go over the image like that?

Comment: give that to the div which contains image and text

Comment: hm. I tried a bit yesterday, but will try again tonight. if  you would like to make it a little more "fool proof" (e.g I am the fool here), than that would be nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jCM7R/ check this fiddle.i hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: yes, that looks very much what I am looking for, thanks! I will accept this as the answer to my (very downvoted) question! thanks man.